# PHP DOMDocument - match and remove URLs

Tags: dom

I'm trying to extract links from html page using DOM:

```
$html = file_get_contents('links.html');
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$a = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($a as $link){
    //echo out the href attribute of the <A> tag.
    echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
http://dontwantthisdomain.com/dont-want-this-domain-name/
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/also-dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://dontwantthisdomain3.com/dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://domain1.com/page-X-on-domain-com.html

http://dontwantthisdomain.com/dont-want-link-from-this-domain-name.html
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://domain.com/page-XZ-on-domain-com.html

http://dontwantthisdomain.com/another-page-from-same-domain-that-i-dont-want-to-be-included/
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/same-as-above/
http://domain3.com/page-XYZ-on-domain3-com.html
```

I would like to remove all results matching dontwantthisdomain.com, dontwantthisdomain2.com and dontwantthisdomain3.com so the output will looks like that:

```
http://domain1.com/page-X-on-domain-com.html
http://domain.com/page-XZ-on-domain-com.html
http://domain3.com/page-XYZ-on-domain3-com.html
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: `$x = new DOMXPath($DOM); $x->query('//a/@href/[not(contains(text(), "dontwantthisdomain"))]);` :P

Comment: @yann-milin could you have a look and let me know what you think? Thanks pal

Comment: @kojiro: it seams that your code is causing errors. Could you veryfie? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use regular expression.Google it and have fun

Comment: Sorted with $html = preg_replace('#<a href="http?://dontwantthisdomain.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $html);